# Selecting starting < character but not continoue with pre or /pre

Tags: regex

I want to select every `<` characters but `<pre` or `</pre` in this document with Regexp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <pre>
        if a < b
    </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: In general, you don't want to process HTML or XML with regular expressions.

Comment: Just for kicks: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1858225  Really, though, it doesn't look like OP is trying to *parse* the regex; this looks more like a simple attempt to highlight all the tags except for `pre` tags, which is definitely simple enough for regex.

Comment: Absolutely you are right Kyle. I just wanted to replace < characters with &lt; for posting an article to my blog. In this way I will have  learned RegEx better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[...]` is for **single character** classes only.
So `[^(pre|/pre)]` means not any of these characters: `(pre|/pre)`
or, equivalently, none of these characters: `)(|/pre`
(since brackets and `|` don't mean anything in `[]` (as far as I remember)).

Then you said it should be optional with `?`, so it doesn't exclude anything.

You probably want look-ahead:

```
\<(?!/?pre)
```

`(?!...)` is negative look-ahead, which "matches" if the next characters **doesn't** match the pattern given inside the brackets.

`/?pre` is a simplification of `pre|/pre`.

Answer (score 1):

That would depend on the regex engine. If it supports Perl regex with [negative lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), you could do

```
<(?!(pre)|(\/pre))
```

or

```
<(?!\/?pre)
```

`group1(?!group2)` means "match `group1` only if the following part doesn't match `group2` (hence the name "negative lookahead". Here `group1` is `<`, and `group2` is `\/?pre`.

Comment: Would you please express what your regex mean? Both of them are working but if you please explain why you used ? or ! it will be better to understand.

Comment: @uzay95 Take a look at the [link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in my answer, it explains it better than I could. I added a short explanation. Dukeling's answer is also essentially equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) a lovely example of why RegEx isn't the best idea for HTML.

Anyway, if you choose to ignore, here is the expression you'll want to use (it will also  handle whitespaces and capitalizations that are valid in HTML)

```
<(?!(\/?\s*[Pp][Rr][Ee]))
```